# Making MEDIAN a function like AVG in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, function

I am new to SQL server.  I need to calculate the median of the time stamp values in my table,

Table1:
_TimeStamp
2009-12-20 11:59:56.0
2009-12-20 11:59:56.5
2009-12-20 11:59:56.3
2009-12-20 11:59:56.4
2009-12-20 11:59:56.4
2009-12-20 11:59:56.9

There is a nice solution to calculating medians here,
[Function to Calculate Median in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342898/function-to-calculate-median-in-sql-server)

For coding simplicity, I would love to implement this as a function in SQL, similar to
    SELECT AVG(_TimeStamp) FROM Table1

but implemented like
    SELECT MEDIAN(_TimeStamp) FROM Table1

Is it possible to save a series of SQL operations as a function that accepts an argument (_TimeStamp) and returns a value (the median)?

Comment: there is no way to do the way you want: **SELECT MEDIAN(_TimeStamp) FROM Table1**.  however, you may be able to create a function where you pass in the table name and do some dynamic SQL.  I would forget about the function and just use this code inline: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342898/function-to-calculate-median-in-sql-server/1567946#1567946

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make a scalar valued function and pass a table valued function as a parameter to it. then return your operation result.

Comment: Is it possible to save a user defined function and then call it from any subsequent SQL query?  Or does the user defined function have to be defined in any SQL query that uses it?  Sorry to ask a basic question but I haven't found a good online guide to user defined functions.

Comment: please see these links :
http://www.sqlteam.com/article/user-defined-functions

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175085%28SQL.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a CLR custom aggregate. I'd be overkill, but technically possible :-).