# Median in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

For even rows formula for median is (104.5 + 108)/2 for table below and For odd rows it is 108 for table below

```
Total       Total

100         100
101         101
104.5       104.5
108         108
108.3       108.3
112         112
            114
```

Code below works in SQL Server 2008 but not in SQL Server 2000 as it does not understand `row_number()` and `over`.

How can we change the lower code to make it work on SQL Server 2000?

```
select avg(Total) median from
(select Total, 
rnasc = row_number() over(order by Total),
rndesc = row_number() over(order by Total desc)
 from [Table] 
) b
where rnasc between rndesc - 1 and rndesc + 1
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only want a median, you may use this simple query.

```
SELECT
(
  (SELECT MAX(Total) FROM
    (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT Total FROM [Table] ORDER BY Total) AS BottomHalf)
  +
  (SELECT MIN(Total) FROM
    (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT Total FROM [Table] ORDER BY Total DESC) AS TopHalf)
) / 2.0 AS Median
```

Source: [Function to Calculate Median in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342898/function-to-calculate-median-in-sql-server/2026609#2026609)

Comment: You mean SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT **Total** not Score, right? Other than that, I think this is really clever.

Comment: And the MAX ones :P.. Another thing you should probably have / 2.0 instead of just with the integer 2 just in case all operands involved in the maths are integers.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Median = AVG(Total) FROM 
( 
    SELECT Total FROM ( 
        SELECT TOP 1 Total = Total * 1.0 FROM 
        ( 
            SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT Total 
            FROM dbo.[Table] ORDER BY Total 
        ) AS sub_a 
        ORDER BY 1 DESC 
    ) AS sub_1 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT Total FROM ( 
        SELECT TOP 1 Total = Total * 1.0 FROM 
        ( 
            SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT Total 
            FROM dbo.[Table] ORDER BY Total DESC 
        ) AS sub_b 
        ORDER BY 1 
    ) AS sub_2 
) AS median;
```