# Function that return the median

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, sql-server-2000, median

I want to create a function that returns the median of a field. I'm working with sql 2000.
I wrote:

```
create function mediana 
(@tabla, @campo)
returns int
as
begin

declare @Median integer
return  @Median = 

(
   (SELECT MAX(@campo) FROM
     (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT dia
      FROM @tabla
      ORDER BY @campo) AS t
    )
 + (SELECT MIN(@campo) FROM
     (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT  @campo
      FROM @tabla ORDER BY @campo DESC) AS b
    )

) / 2.0 ;
```

But I get many errors. How can I solve that, also I would like to apply this function to data grouped by other fiels. Would this be possible with this code?

ps: I've never created a function in sql before.

thanks

Comment: Well where did you find syntax like `return @Median =`? Did you make that up? I mean, there *is* [documentation to consult](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258261(v=sql.80).aspx).

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL if you are passing in a table name.  I don't think SQL Server 2000 supports table valued parameters, and syntax isn't right for that anyway.

Comment: `I get many errors` -- and those errors are...?

Comment: @Gordon perhaps, I have never seen it ([and can't get `return @var = anything` to work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68b32/548)), still the input parameters don't have types, no schema on the function, no `END`... basically a "find all the things wrong in this picture" exercise.

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . I didn't mean "syntax", I meant "logic".

Comment: @AaronBertrand ok I know it's wrong. that's why I'm asking. Would you please correct me?

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, I think I'm familiar with the logic (see [here](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/median) and [here](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/02/t-sql-queries/grouped-median)) - the OP is complaining about syntax errors.

Comment: You need to write a function that compiles; please [consult the docs I've already pointed you to](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258261(v=sql.80).aspx) and give up on the idea that you can pass a table name to a function.

Comment: really? @AaronBertrand, you are a genious! yes I download it from there! and now, can someone please help me to do what I'm asking: I want to create a function and store it to apply it to other variables. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Why divide by 2.0 when returning int? do you need decimal or not?

Comment: @AaronBertrand did we have QUOTENAME() function in Sql Server 2000 ? I am not sure, because this can make my suggested solution much safer, could you please confirm if we had that function in SQL Server 2000 or not ?

Comment: @M.Ali [Yes, you can check the documentation, I am not a library](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238369(v=sql.80).aspx). :-)

Comment: Thank you I was searching it but couldn't find it :)

Comment: @M.Ali I searched [`quotename sql server 2000`](https://www.google.com/search?q=quotename+sql+server+2000) - first hit. Not sure how you would have searched differently for that.

Comment: Here is some light reading for you.  http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/sql-server-2012-solutions-median-calculation

Comment: My Search returned this [`Page`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms176114.aspx) and it doesnt show option for 2000 version :S my bad

Comment: @AaronBertrand, is your answer to this question any good?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310335/median-in-sql-server-2000

Comment: @Dan not really, the OP is having fundamental problems with FUNCTION syntax and the logic of passing table and column names dynamically, not any difficulty with calculating median per se.

Answer (score -1):

When passing Table names of Column names as variables, you will end up using Dynamic sql, and you cannot use Dynamic sql inside a User defined Function this leaves you with the only option of stored procedure, 
Since you are returning a value back, OUTPUT parameter is your friend something like this .....

```
ALTER PROCEDURE mediana 
 @tabla nvarchar(128)
,@campo nvarchar(128)
,@Median DECIMAL(10,2) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(2000);

SET @Sql = N'SET @Median =  ( SELECT 
                (
                 (SELECT MAX('+ QUOTENAME(@campo) +') FROM
                   (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT '+ QUOTENAME(@campo) +' FROM '+ QUOTENAME(@tabla) 
                 + N' ORDER BY '+ QUOTENAME(@campo) +') AS BottomHalf)
                 +
                 (SELECT MIN('+ QUOTENAME(@campo) +') FROM
                   (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT '+ QUOTENAME(@campo) +' FROM '+ QUOTENAME(@tabla) 
                 + N' ORDER BY '+ QUOTENAME(@campo) +' DESC) AS TopHalf)
                ) / 2  )'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
                     ,N'@Median DECIMAL(10,2) OUTPUT'
                     ,@Median OUTPUT

END
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I use it? Would be something like mediana(@tabla=tbl1, @campo=field1)???

Comment: You're not going to be able to use this in select statements, though

Comment: Didnt test it before, have tested it and it is working