# SQL Median hits per user?

Tags: php, mysql, statistics

I have a MySQL table which tracks hits like so:

- id (int autoincrement)
- unique (text, unique identifier of user - basically md5'd IP)
- date (int, unix timestamp)

I know I can find the *average* page views per user by simply taking `count(id) / count(unique)`, but is there any way to find a median page views per user?

Also, I feel as though my population base consists of a group of recurring users, and a lot of users who only visit once and leave.  What kind of formulas can I use to create data about this?  I was thinking about creating some kind of metric based on *number of hits for that user* times *total time between first and last visit*, but I'm unsure if this will really provide useful data as I don't actually have a clear picture of my traffic / revisit patterns.  If anybody has other metrics they've used that work I'd really like to hear them!

I don't need the implementation to be entirely in MySQL - I'm running on a php server.  The code doesn't have to be particularly efficient, as it's only called when I load my admin dashboard.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Just use Google Analytics, it provides a clear picture of traffic and revisit patterns.

Comment: This would be good for the future, but I want to analyze my existing 60k hits.

Comment: Ah, good luck with that.

Comment: Not sure if this sql server specific: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342898/function-to-calculate-median-in-sql-server