# how to get median for every record?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

There's no median function in sql server, so I'm using this wonderful suggestion:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2026609/117700

this computes the median over an entire dataset, but I need the median per record.

My dataset is:

```
+-----------+-------------+
| client_id | TimesTested |
+-----------+-------------+
|    214220 |           1 |
|    215425 |           1 |
|    212839 |           4 |
|    215249 |           1 |
|    210498 |           3 |
|    110655 |           1 |
|    110655 |           1 |
|    110655 |          12 |
|    215425 |           4 |
|    100196 |           1 |
|    110032 |           1 |
|    110032 |           1 |
|    101944 |           3 |
|    101232 |           2 |
|    101232 |           1 |
+-----------+-------------+
```

here's the query I am using:

```
select client_id,  
    (
    SELECT
    (
     (SELECT MAX(TimesTested ) FROM
       (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT t.TimesTested 
       FROM counted3 t 
       where t.timestested>1 
       and CLIENT_ID=t.CLIENT_ID 
       ORDER BY t.TimesTested ) AS BottomHalf)
     +
     (SELECT MIN(TimesTested ) FROM
       (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT t.TimesTested 
       FROM counted3 t 
       where t.timestested>1 
       and CLIENT_ID=t.CLIENT_ID 
       ORDER BY t.TimesTested DESC) AS TopHalf)
    ) / 2 AS Median
    ) TotalAvgTestFreq
from counted3 

group by client_id
```

but it is giving my funny data:

```
+-----------+------------------+
| client_id | median???????????|
+-----------+------------------+
|    100007 |               84 |
|    100008 |               84 |
|    100011 |               84 |
|    100014 |               84 |
|    100026 |               84 |
|    100027 |               84 |
|    100028 |               84 |
|    100029 |               84 |
|    100042 |               84 |
|    100043 |               84 |
|    100071 |               84 |
|    100072 |               84 |
|    100074 |               84 |
+-----------+------------------+
```

**i can i get the median for every client_id ?**

I am currently trying to use this **awesome** query from Aaron's site:

```
select c3.client_id,(
    SELECT AVG(1.0 * TimesTested ) median
    FROM
    (
        SELECT o.TimesTested , 
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o.TimesTested ), c.c
        FROM counted3 AS o
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT c = COUNT(*) FROM counted3) AS c
        where count>1
    ) AS x
    WHERE rn IN ((c + 1)/2, (c + 2)/2)
    ) a
    from counted3 c3
    group by c3.client_id
```

unfortunately, as Richardthekiwi points out:

> it's for a single median whereas this question is about a median
>   per-partition

i would like to know how i can join it on `counted3` to get the median per partition?>

Comment: What do you mean, "median per record"?

Comment: @Lamak i mean for all the values for client_id 100007 i want to get the median

Comment: if 100007 has timestested 1, 1,1,1,2,4,5,7,8,99 then the median woudl be 4

Comment: Ok, Then you should update your dataset since it shows unique `client_id`s and they are different from your result set

Comment: There are many ways, I profiled the fastest here (hint: it's not the approach you're using): http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/median

Comment: On the inner most queries, you say: ` and CLIENT_ID=t.CLIENT_ID ` which is the same as ` and t.CLIENT_ID=t.CLIENT_ID ` - in other words, a non-sensical join condition. You need to reference the outer table as Sebastien has indicated. Also, why not include sample data in your question that actually matches your results? Why are the client_ids not the same?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I thought op said that he already fixed the sample and results data, but alas, I didn't check

Comment: Nope. The lowest `client_id` in your "dataset" is 100196. The highest `client_id` in your "funny data" is 100074.

Comment: @AaronBertrand i used the query on your site by the israeli guy. it's very fast, but returned ALL NULLS

Comment: this one SELECT @Median = AVG(1.0 * val)
FROM
(
    SELECT o.val, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o.val), c.c
    FROM dbo.EvenRows AS o
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT c = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.EvenRows) AS c
) AS x
WHERE rn IN ((c + 1)/2, (c + 2)/2);

Comment: @Aaron - while your blog is interesting, it's for a single median whereas this question is about a median *per-partition* (client_id).

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi while true, you can't just take the code from the blog, I expect people who are programming for a living to be able to extend what we've done for them to some degree. You'll also note that I didn't post it as an *answer*. Therefore I was not stating or even implying that I had code to provide a complete answer - just something to look at, not to be nit-picked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: If testFreq is an `int` or `bigint` type, you need to CAST it before taking an average, otherwise you'll get integer division, e.g. `(2+5)/2 => 3` if 2 and 5 are the median records - e.g. `AVG(Cast(testfreq as float))`.

```
select client_id, avg(testfreq) median_testfreq
from
(
    select client_id,
           testfreq,
           rn=row_number() over (partition by CLIENT_ID
                                 order by testfreq),
           c=count(testfreq) over (partition by CLIENT_ID)
    from tbk
    where timestested>1
) g
where rn in (round(c/2,0),c/2+1)
group by client_id;
```

The median is found either as the central record in an ODD number of rows, or the average of the two central records in an EVEN number of rows.  This is handled by the condition `rn in (round(c/2,0),c/2+1)` which picks either the one or two records required.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select client_id,  
    (
    SELECT
    (
     (SELECT MAX(testfreq) FROM
       (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT t.testfreq 
       FROM counted3 t 
       where t.timestested>1 
       and c3.CLIENT_ID=t.CLIENT_ID 
       ORDER BY t.testfreq) AS BottomHalf)
     +
     (SELECT MIN(testfreq) FROM
       (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT t.testfreq 
       FROM counted3 t 
       where t.timestested>1 
       and c3.CLIENT_ID=t.CLIENT_ID 
       ORDER BY t.testfreq DESC) AS TopHalf)
    ) / 2 AS Median
    ) TotalAvgTestFreq
from counted3 c3

group by client_id
```

I added the c3 alias to the outer CLIENT_ID references and the outer table.

Comment: thank you very much that's probably what the problem was but unfortunately this query has been running for liek 15 min so far