# Displaying the median in an SSRS chart

Tags: charts, ssrs-2008, median

I am developing a bar chart report in SSRS 2008.  I simply want the bars in the bar chart to represent the median of a value from the query this is using.  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by calculating the median in the query instead of trying to get SSRS to do that for me.  I used this to do that in the query:  [Function to Calculate Median in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342898/function-to-calculate-median-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly there is no built-in function for Median in either SSRS or T-SQL (assuming that is your data source). I would add the code to pre-calculate this to the query, then SSRS can just present it.

The starting point for T-SQL is the NTILE function:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx

Note my comments in the "Community Additions" section - there are a few pitfalls for the unwary.