# Calculate SQL Median

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I was trying to implement a median from this solution (among others, but this seemed the simplest Median code): [Function to Calculate Median in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342898/function-to-calculate-median-in-sql-server)

However, I'm having difficulty in its application.  This is my current SQL query.  My goal is to find the Median `TotalTimeOnCall` for `CallerComplaintTypeID` on a given Week, Month, and Department.  I think my biggest issue is that I'm just fundamentally not understanding how to apply this Median function to achieve my results.

For example, if I needed an Average, instead, I could just change that `ORDER BY` to a `GROUP BY` and then slap an `AVG(TotalTimeOnCall)` instead.  How do I accomplish this idea with this Median solution, instead?

This is the "raw data" query:

```
WITH rawData as (
SELECT 
    DepartmentName
    ,MONTH(PlacedOnLocal) AS MonthNumber
    ,CASE 
    WHEN Datepart(day, PlacedOnLocal) < 8 THEN '1' 
    WHEN Datepart(day, PlacedOnLocal) < 15 THEN '2' 
    WHEN Datepart(day, PlacedOnLocal) < 22 THEN '3' 
    WHEN Datepart(day, PlacedOnLocal) < 29 THEN '4' 
    ELSE '5' 
    END AS WeekNumber
    ,CallerComplaintTypeID
    ,TotalTimeOnCall
FROM [THE_RELEVANT_TABLE]
WHERE PlacedOnLocal BETWEEN '2014-09-01' AND '2014-12-31'
    AND CallerComplaintTypeID IN (5,89,9,31,203)
    AND TotalTimeOnCall IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT 
DepartmentName,
MonthNumber,
WeekNumber,
CallerComplaintTypeID,
TotalTimeOnCall
FROM
rawData
ORDER BY DepartmentName, MonthNumber, WeekNumber, CallerComplaintTypeID
```

with this sample output:

```
DepartmentName  MonthNumber WeekNumber  CallerComplaintTypeID   TotalTimeOnCall
Dept_01     9   1   5   654
Dept_01     9   1   5   156
Dept_01     9   1   5   21
Dept_01     9   1   5   67
Dept_01     9   1   5   13
Dept_01     9   1   5   97
Dept_01     9   1   5   87
Dept_01     9   1   5   16
```

this is the Median solution from above:

```
SELECT
(
    (
        SELECT MAX(TotalTimeOnCall)
        FROM
            (
                SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT TotalTimeOnCall
                FROM rawData
                WHERE TotalTimeOnCall IS NOT NULL
                ORDER BY TotalTimeOnCall
            ) AS BottomHalf
    )
    +
    (
        SELECT MIN(TotalTimeOnCall)
        FROM
            (
                SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT TotalTimeOnCall
                FROM rawData
                WHERE TotalTimeOnCall IS NOT NULL
                ORDER BY TotalTimeOnCall DESC
            ) AS TopHalf
    )
) / 2 AS Median
```

Comment: That median approach does not support per-group medians.  It can compute only whole-table medians.  You could consider instead creating a user-defined `MEDIAN()` aggregate function.

Comment: Alternatively, I suspect the `ROW_NUMBER()`-based alternative also presented as an answer to the question you linked could be adapted to grouped medians, but I'm not prepared to work out the details.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks, I was able to piece something together from that that works nicely.

Comment: http://sqlperformance.com/2014/02/t-sql-queries/grouped-median

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple median solution that allows you to get a median per group.

```
-- Example of how to get median from a set of data
;with cte_my_query as (
    -- this cte simulates the query that would return your data
    select '2016-01-01' as dt, 1 as val
    union 
    select '2016-01-01' as dt, 10 as val
    union 
    select '2016-01-01' as dt, 7 as val
    union 
    select '2016-01-01' as dt, 16 as val
    union 
    select '2016-01-01' as dt, 11 as val
    union 
    select '2016-01-01' as dt, 2 as val
    union
    select '2016-01-01' as dt, 5 as val
    union 
    select '2016-01-02' as dt, 6 as val
    union 
    select '2016-01-02' as dt, 13 as val
    union 
    select '2016-01-02' as dt, 7 as val
    union   
    select '2016-01-02' as dt, 9 as val
    union   
    select '2016-01-02' as dt, 18 as val
)
,cte_dates as (
    -- get the distinct key we want to get median for
    select distinct dt from cte_my_query
)
select  dt, median.val
from    cte_dates
    cross apply (
        -- of the top 50% (below), take the top 1, desc, which is the median value
        select top 1 val from (
            -- for each date, get the top 50% of the values
            select top 50 percent val
            from cte_my_query
            where cte_dates.dt = cte_my_query.dt
            order by dt
        ) as inner_median
        order by inner_median.val desc
    ) median
```