# Median worked out incorrectly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, median

I have tried all possibilities in working out the Median value on a specific column but keep on getting a different value from Excel.

I am working on SQL2008R2

This is what I have tried so far :

```
SELECT  Entity,
                BillPeriod,
                Cost,
                PatientDays,
                0 AS Median
        FROM GroupCTE
        UNION 
        SELECT  Entity,
                BillPeriod,
                Cost,
                PatientDays,
                0 AS Median
        FROM RegionCTE
                    UNION 
        SELECT  Entity,
                BillPeriod,
                Cost,
                PatientDays,
                0 AS Median
        FROM InstitutionCTE
        Union
        SELECT  'Median' as Entity,
                BillPeriod,
                0 as Cost,
                0 as PatientDays,
                (((
                    (SELECT MAX(Cost) FROM
                        (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT Cost FROM InstitutionCTE WHERE Cost <> 0 ORDER BY Cost ASC) AS BottomHalf)
                    +
                    (SELECT MIN(Cost) FROM
                        (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT Cost FROM InstitutionCTE WHERE Cost <> 0 ORDER BY Cost DESC) AS TopHalf)
                )) / 2)  AS Median
```

Am I doing something terribly wrong here?

I tried this : [Function to Calculate Median in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342898/function-to-calculate-median-in-sql-server)

Thank you

Comment: You could watch this, Itzik Ben-Gan gives some good examples how to calculate median: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=goyWzAu-AA0

Comment: This calculation doesn't match with the definition of Median. Whereas Excel Median function might be implementing the exact formula for median. So you see difference in the result.

Comment: (1) Provide an example of how the calculation is incorrect.  (2) If `cost` is an integer, then you are doing integer division.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, with the current data, I get a big difference when comparing to SQL results : SQL - 401970.095 Excel - 397361.495. Cost data type is float.

Comment: Count the number of values bigger and less than those values and figure out which is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to fix this issue.
The problem was, for some reason, doing the Median calculation gave be different results than that of Excels Median function.

I created a TEMP table and imported the result of my UNION, then updated the Median column using my calculation :

```
INSERT INTO #Temp
            SELECT  Entity,
                    BillPeriod,
                    ((Cost) / (PatientDays)) * 100 AS Cost,
                    PatientDays,
                    0 AS Median
            FROM GroupCTE
            UNION 
            SELECT  Entity,
                    BillPeriod,
                    ((Cost) / (PatientDays)) * 100 AS Cost,
                    PatientDays,
                    0 AS Median
            FROM RegionCTE
            UNION 
            SELECT  Entity,
                    BillPeriod,
                    ((Cost) / (PatientDays)) * 100 AS Cost,
                    PatientDays,
                    0 AS Median
            FROM InstitutionCTE
            UNION       
            SELECT  'Median' as Entity,
                    BillPeriod,
                    0 AS Cost,
                    0 AS PatientDays,
                    0 AS Median


            FROM InstitutionCTE
            GROUP BY Entity, BillPeriod, PatientDays

            UPDATE #Temp
            SET Median =    ((
                        ((SELECT MAX(Cost) FROM
                            (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT Cost FROM #Temp WHERE Cost <> 0 ORDER BY Cost ASC) AS BottomHalf)
                        +
                        (SELECT MIN(Cost) FROM
                            (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT Cost FROM #Temp WHERE Cost <> 0 ORDER BY Cost DESC) AS TopHalf)
                    )) / 2)     


SELECT * FROM #Temp
DROP TABLE #Temp
```