# How to express Excel formula MEDIAN(MOD(B2,1),$E$2,$D$2) in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me in converting Excel formula:

```
F=MEDIAN(MOD(B2,1),$E$2,$D$2)
```

where B2 is Date value and E2 is Endtime and D2 is start Time.

```
Example Date: 5/2/2016 22:35
Start Time: 12:00:00 AM 
End Time: 11:59:59 PM
```

I tried this but no correct output:

```
declare @dtColumn  datetime
declare @dtColumn1  time
set @dtColumn='5/2/2016  10:35:00 PM'
set @dtColumn1=CONVERT(char(8),CAST(AVG(CAST(@dtColumn AS FLOAT) - FLOOR(CAST(@dtColumn AS FLOAT))) AS datetime),108)
print @dtColumn1
```

I should get output as 0.94 from Excel formula. Please help me how to convert it to SQL Server query.

Comment: Result from  formula= 0.94

Comment: There is no standard median aggregation function in SQL Server. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342898/function-to-calculate-median-in-sql-server

Comment: I need query for Median and MOD in SQL for Date and start and end time as given in example

Comment: When you run the SQL, what result do you get? You've stated what you are aiming for, always state what you are getting currently as well.

Comment: Here I am want Turn around time calculation from above formula

Comment: Formula IF(NETWORKDAYS($BD$2,$BD$2,$BA$2:$BA$60),MEDIAN(MOD($BD$2,1),$BB$2,$BC$2),$BC$2)-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS(J2,J2,$BA$2:$BA$60)*MOD(J2,1),$BB$2,$BC$2)