# How to annotate median value to django queryset

Tags: sql, django, sqlite, mariadb, django-annotate

I have 2 models Puzzle and Play. for each play I have a rating.
I would like to annotate to a Puzzle queryset the median rating value for all corresponding plays.

```
class Puzzle(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Play(models.Model):
    puzzle = models.ForeignKey(Puzzle, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='plays')
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=-1)
    puzzle_completed = models.BooleanField(default=None, blank=False, null=False)
```

I know how to count:

```
Puzzle.objects.annotate(nb_sucesses=Count('plays', filter = Q(plays__puzzle_completed=True), distinct = True),)
```

and I expected getting the median in a similar way:

```
Puzzle.objects.annotate(rating_median=Median('plays__rating', filter = Q(plays__puzzle_completed=True), distinct = True),)
```

however, apparently due to my Django development environnment database (**sqlite**), I'm not able to do that.

From what I infered from the following info https://mariadb.com/kb/en/median/, in my production environment(**MariaDB**), this approach should work (but I didn't tested it yet)

My current understanding (based on different internet searches) is that I should be able to use Django Func() function to use a custom Median function ([following that model ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46689979/how-to-make-use-a-custom-database-function-in-django)) that would either call Median if in production, or a more complicated sql raw query if in Development (based [on this one ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763965/how-can-i-calculate-the-median-of-values-in-sqlite/29092063#29092063) or [on this one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43430759/how-to-extract-median-value)).

But after a few hours, I must admit I am out of my depth here.

Anyone could please help me connect the dots ?

Comment: `Median` is, to the best of my knowledge, not an SQL aggregate function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/942940/67579

Comment: It is available in MariaDB 10.3.3, but not (yet) in MySQL 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found out a package with a robust and multi-database implementation of Median and percentile for Django:
https://github.com/ankane/tailslide/

it enables user to perform the following:

```
from tailslide import Median, Percentile

Item.objects.aggregate(Median('price'))
Request.objects.aggregate(Percentile('response_time', .95))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no Median implementation in Django as it is not implemented in PostgreSQL.

You can run [median](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/median/) on MariaDB 10.3.3+ as raw query or write yourself an [aggregate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#creating-your-own-aggregate-functions) function inside Django for your custom needs which will then translate to same query using ORM

You should definitely have same db type on production and dev environment to minimize bugs due different environment ( suggesting also to use tools like docker)

Answer (score 0):

For how to do this when using PostgreSQL refer to 
my answer at [Django & Postgres - percentile (median) and group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59686945/django-postgres-percentile-median-and-group-by/61938397#61938397).

One can create a `Median` child class of `Aggregate`, which then behaves like the other aggregation functions.