# How to calculate the median of a row in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, median

I am new to sql and have been struggling about nan-median, for example, I have a table with three (million) rows, each with ten numbers (or null):

```
row1: 1,2,3,null,4,5,6,7,8,9
----------
row2: 2,4,null,6,8,2,1,0,9,10
----------
row3: 1,1,1,1,null,7,2,9,9,9
----------
```

How to get the **nan-median** of each **row**?

Comment: this may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342898/function-to-calculate-median-in-sql-server

Comment: if i understand correctly, that post is about calculating median of a column, I am trying to figure out how to calculate median of a row.

Comment: Do your rows have a primary key?

Comment: @MBurnham yes I use the auto_increment index as a primary key

Comment: can you provide schema for table?

Comment: @MBurnham, TB( id (pri), field1, field2......field10 (float NULL) ), basically 11 columns with id column as primary key, three rows, or three million rows...

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Looks like you are having problems with the null values. For that use the coalesce function e.g. coalesce (Col1, 0).

Comment: There is no easy way to get the median without ordering your columns. Unfortunately (for you), mysql doesn't provide a function to order columns, just rows (data of same meaning is usually stored in the same column). You can create rows out of your columns (`select id, col1 from table union all select id, col2 from table union all ...`) and then use any of the median queries for rows. Or, probably faster, write a function that takes 10 values, orders them and thus calculates the median row wise.

Comment: @Solarflare, I guess there is indeed no easy way to do it, the data is a time series (row) with ten station sensors, there is no easy way to switch rows and columns either, I managed to use R to deal with it and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, If you have 10 columns that you want to calculate. 
The trick is to avoid the null values with `Coalesce` function.
Use this logic:

```
Select (coalesce(Col1, 0) + coalesce(Col2, 0) + coalesce(Col3, 0)+ coalesce(Col4, 0)+coalesce(Col5, 0)+coalesce(Col6, 0)+coalesce(Col7, 0)+coalesce(Col8, 0)+coalesce(Col9, 0)+.coalesce(Col10, 0))/10 
from yourtable
```

Comment: That is the average. The median in the value that seperates the top half and the lower half of elements (e.g.: the 5th element for a list of 9 elements and the average of the 5th and 6th element for a list of 10 elements).

Answer (score 0):

```
select(
   (select MAX(cols) from 
    (select TOP 50 PERCENT cols from table ORDER BY cols) )  
        + 
          (select MIN(cols) from 
            (select TOP 50 PERCENT cols from table ORDER BY cols DESC) ) 
     ) / 2  
Median
```

Select max of first 50% rows by sorting the rows in asc which should be the median in case if column count is even. Select min of next 50% rows by ordering the rows in desc, in case if column count is even, this will be median or else max of (firsthalf+min of secondhalf)/2 will be the median.

Comment: Good answer but MySQL's dialect does not have `TOP` clause.

Comment: Didn't LIMIT 50 PERCENT replaces the same when it comes to mysql? Just a thought, correct me if wrong! @Parfait

Comment: An often [asked question](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=mysql+limit+percent), no such clause.

Comment: How about this? Select * from (Select * from (select count(*)/2 from INFORMATION_SCHEME.COLUMNS where table_scheme='schema' and table_name=&#39;table&#39;) as cnt limit cnt) order by desc limit 1

Doing the same and sorting another 50% in asc as suggested in my answer. I think this will work.

Comment: can the 50 percent order method deal with NULLs automatically?

Comment: You can use coalesce(val,0) to handle nulls since IsNull() is not an ANSI-SQL compliant. And here, it actually handles null. I&#39;m ordering the records before picking the data. So probably null might not be an obstacle. But there are some special cases like 5,null,null and null,null which wouldn&#39;t work. But he didn:t mention anything about what to return when these cases occur.

Comment: He wants the median of 10 columns, not rows. (The median of the content of `(col1, col2, col3... col10) ` per row).