# Finding median from sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

A median is defined as a number separating the higher half of a data set from the lower half. Query the median of the Northern Latitudes (LAT_N) from STATION and round your answer to decimal places.

Input Format

The STATION table is described as follows:

[image]

where LAT_N is the northern latitude and LONG_W is the western longitude.

I wrote the query as:

```
select round(LAT_N,4) from (select LAT_N from station order by LAT_N) where ROWNUM = ((LENGTH(LAT_N)+1)/2);
```

I am not getting the output from this query.
Can anyone explain what's the error?

Comment: "Wrong Answer" is highly unlikely to be a message from an SQL compiler.  The LENGTH() function is something quite different from the cardinality of a relation, which must be obtained using SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...  Whether your solution is dependable, depending on ROWNUM being always equal to a row's rank, may be uncertain.

Comment: Which database server do you use ? Please use appropriate tag.

Comment: I would love to know what compiler it is that returns such a intriguing error message as "Wrong Answer" :)

Comment: @DraganJovanović Oracle.
I was practicing on online website.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Sorry my bad. Compiler is not throwing Wrong Answer as error.
As I was practicing online so it was just checking with the correct output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2026609/1693085

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle, probably the simplest way is to use [`median()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions086.htm):

```
select median(LAT_N) 
from stations;
```

Comment: Thanks..
But can you explain what's wrong in my query.

Comment: @AayushChachan `rownum` is assigned to rows as they are returned, so the first row is 1, the next is 2 etc. Therefore predicates like `where rownum = 2` will never be true. Also, `length(lat_n)` returns the number of characters in the string (e.g. `length('xyz')` returns 3), not the number of rows in a set.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way :

```
select top 1 a.LAT_N, count(*) biggerThan
from
(select LAT_N from station) a join (select LAT_N from station) b on a.LAT_N > b.LAT_N
    join (select count(*) countt from station) counterr on 1 = 1
group by a.LAT_N, counterr.countt
having count(*) > counterr.countt/2 - 1
order by biggerThan
```

It returns the smallest value which is bigger than approximately half of set members.
I have defined "approximately half" as countt/2 - 1, and you should probably be more precise with this part of logic.

Comment: Why should we go with such long query for this problem?

Comment: I am not aware of shorter solution in standard sql, and I'd like to see it. 
Information about Oracle server wasn't available at the moment I started making this solution.

Comment: Sorry for missing the oracle tag