# How to pick up median value in between 3 records? - SQL

Tags: sql, median

Please assist me, I need to pick 790 since its in middle but not able to figure it out.

```
id  Value
12  780
123 796
124  790
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You've been an SO member for 5 years. You should know this is not a high quality post.

Comment: Please tell us which database you are using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.).

Comment: I am sorry @dfundako, I am using SQL database Tim

Comment: @user2711165 The question is which one?

Comment: For SQL server see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342898/function-to-calculate-median-in-sql-server

Comment: @magnus, I had looked at it already and it did not work for me as I already have the median value.

Answer (score 0):

This should help to get what you want. Get the average value from your table, then get first record with smallest difference with average value.

```
SELECT TOP 1 id, value FROM yourTable
ORDER BY ABS(value - (SELECT AVG(value) FROM yourTable))
```

or using variables, depending on the size of your table

```
DECLARE @median DECIMAL
SELECT @median = AVG(value) FROM yourTable

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM yourTable 
ORDER BY ABS( value - @median)
```