# Sum all columns by omitting 3 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with more than 34 columns.

I need to aggregate(sum) of the columns.

To find:

1. Sum of 2 columns
2. Sum of remaining columns except.

Please find the table structure with following columns.

```
S.NO              
Handling charge
Storage Charge
...
..
.... 34th column charge
```

I have more than 3000 rows of records based on above mentioned columns.

May I know how to query or calculate above mentioned find.

For Find 1 Query:

```
**Update dbo.tablename
set columnname isnull(charge1,0)+isnull(charge2,0)**
```

I am struggling to find find 2:

Can anyone help?

Comment: add more details of your table

Comment: probably same as this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52727267/sql-operation-on-the-column-sum-of-a-table/52727804#52727804

Comment: Without mentioning sum(col1+col2+col3+...) is there any query sumallcolumns(except 2 columns) because charges name keep on changing.

Comment: There is no way something like you want. If you want to write a dynamic query, you need to extract the table's column from "sys.columns" in "master" database and create a query string and execute it using "execute()" function. I do not suggest you this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the table to get the list of columns name then apply the Sum() function.

Query table column names:

```
SELECT *
FROM DatabaseName.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'tableName'
```

Comment: I tried with this query, but it returns null. Query I tried select * from bireports.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = N'fcl'. It reurns nothing.

Comment: So I used below Following query to list the column names,SELECT *
FROM [Powerbireports].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'FCL_Pivot' and column_name like '%Charges'. Hereafter how can I perform sum and exclude two columns?

Comment: You have to exclude the two columns in the where condition ex: where column_name<>'Excluded_Columns_Name'