# How can I find median in sql

Tags: sql, redash

How can I find median in sql. I am trying

```
select 
 date, 
 sum(amount), 
 median(amount), 
 count(user) 
from table
group by 1
```

It shows an error that

> function median(double precision) does not exist

Comment: Welcome to SO, please research other questions before posting as there is an abundance of similar material on this topic already available here. here's just one link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342898/function-to-calculate-median-in-sql-server

Comment: A solution for a median is rather DBMS specific.  So like Gordon asked, tag your question. And probably also mention the version. Some examples: MS Sql Server 2012, MySql 8.0, Oracle 12c, PostgreSql 11

Comment: No median function on sql, your looking for percentile_disc or percentile_cont

Comment: You can refactor your query, and create a subquery which will return median and group by 1st column. to get the median you can sort the amount column and choose the row_num/2. or something like that

Comment: @AvinashKumar which kind of dataset are you connected to?

Answer (score 0):

Try if this standard sql works.

```
select 
    t.[date]
    ,sum(amount) ttl_amount
    ,(select sum(s.amount) / (select ((count(*) + 1) % 2) + 1 from @table s where s.[date] = t.[date])
            from (select s.amount
                    from @table s 
                    where t.date = s.date 
                    order by s.amount asc 
                    offset (select ((count(*) - (count(*) + 1) % 2) / 2) from @table s where s.[date] = t.[date]) rows fetch next 
                           (select ((count(*) + 1) % 2) + 1              from @table s where s.[date] = t.[date]) rows only ) s ) median
    ,count(distinct [user]) dst_user
from @table t
group by [date]
```