# With MySQL, how to calculate a MEDIAN with Left Join records?

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the following two tables, I'd like to know how to calculate the MEDIAN rating for reviews on a weekly basis.

**reviews**

```
(id, user_id, completed_at)

reviews.completed_at -- lets us know the user submitted the review, it's not a draft.
```

**reviews_areas**

```
reviews_areas (created_at, review_id, rating)

reviews_areas.rating = INT between 0…10)
```

Example Data:

**reviews:**

```
+----+---------+---------------------+
| id | user_id |    completed_at     |
+----+---------+---------------------+
|  1 |     100 | 2019-07-20 11:34:40 |
|  2 |     100 | 2019-07-22 11:34:40 |
|  3 |     500 | 2019-07-30 16:34:40 |
+----+---------+---------------------+
```

**reviews_areas:**

```
+------------+-----------+--------+
| created_at | review_id | rating |
+------------+-----------+--------+
| 1:34:40    |         1 |      0 |
| 12:34:40   |         1 |      5 |
| 11:34:40   |         1 |     10 |
| 5:34:40    |         1 |      9 |
| 6:34:40    |         2 |      1 |
| 1:34:40    |         2 |      5 |
| 2:32:40    |         3 |      5 |
+------------+-----------+--------+
```

Comment: Median of what?

Comment: I think rating)

Comment: My apologies, the median of the ratings

Comment: what does the `reviews_areas` table mean? `created_at` stores without date? We need to extract week from `completed_at` column in `reviews`?

Comment: reviews.completed_at -- lets us know the user submitted the review, it's not a draft.

Comment: answer other questions please so that I can help you

Comment: `reviews_areas` is areas in the reviews... Think of Yelp, you rate the restaurant and then you can optionally rate multiple aspects like price, food quality, friendlieness etc... You have to rate at least one reviews_areas but you are not limitied to just 1. does that help?

Comment: Is the week from `reviews.completed_at` or `reviews_areas.created_at`? If it's `reviews_areas.created_at`, how do we get the week from a time?

Comment: We could do something like `floor(datediff(reviews.created_at, curdate()) / 7) AS weeks_ago and then `GROUP BY weeks_ago
ORDER BY weeks_ago DESC` - what do you think of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not clear. I'll use `reviews.completed_at` for the date because `reviews_areas.created_at` contains just a time.

We need to [join](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/33052/%2fArticles%2f33052%2fVisual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins) `reviews` for the date with `reviews_areas` for the rating.

To avoid the same week on different years from overlapping, we use [`yearweek`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek) to turn dates into the year + week.

To get the median we need to find the middle row (or rows if there's an even number) for each week. There's many ways to do this. I'll crib [from Justin Grant's clever answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1567946/14660). We count the `row_number()` ordered ascending and descending. Where they overlap +/- 1 are the median rows. Then we average them.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
6 5 4 3 2 1
    ^^^
    median rows
```

First, we get the row numbers by week.

```
select
    yearweek(completed_at) as week,
    rating,
    row_number() over(
        partition by yearweek(completed_at)
        order by rating asc, id asc
    ) as row_asc,
    row_number() over(
        partition by yearweek(completed_at)
        order by rating desc, id desc
    ) as row_desc
from reviews_areas ra
join reviews r on r.id = ra.review_id
```

The row numbers are ordered by `order by rating asc, id asc`. The `id` is a secondary sort to disambiguate rows with the same rating.

```
+--------+--------+---------+----------+
| week   | rating | row_asc | row_desc |
+--------+--------+---------+----------+
| 201928 |     10 |       4 |        1 |
| 201928 |      9 |       3 |        2 |
| 201928 |      5 |       2 |        3 |
| 201928 |      0 |       1 |        4 |
| 201929 |      5 |       2 |        1 |
| 201929 |      1 |       1 |        2 |
| 201930 |      5 |       1 |        1 |
+--------+--------+---------+----------+
```

Then we use that as a [common table expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) to average the middle rows of each week. A subquery works just as well.

```
with rating_weeks as (
    select
        yearweek(completed_at) as week,
        rating,
        row_number() over(
            partition by yearweek(completed_at)
            order by rating asc, id asc
        ) as row_asc,
        row_number() over(
            partition by yearweek(completed_at)
            order by rating desc, id desc
        ) as row_desc
    from reviews_areas ra
    join reviews r on r.id = ra.review_id
)
select
    week,
    -- Take the average of the possibly 2 median rows
    avg(rating)
from rating_weeks
where
    -- Find the rows which overlap +/- 1. These are the median rows.
    row_asc in (row_desc, row_desc - 1, row_desc + 1)
group by week
order by week
```

```
+--------+-------------+
| week   | avg(rating) |
+--------+-------------+
| 201928 |      7.0000 |
| 201929 |      3.0000 |
| 201930 |      5.0000 |
+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: Sorry, but the average is not a median

Comment: @Schwern, fyi, this is AVG, not MEDIAN

Comment: @AnApprentice My mistake. I've changed it to do the median. I learned a lot writing up this answer. Like why doesn't SQL have a median function?!