# Computing the median of all users in all trips

Tags: postgresql, statistics, aggregate-functions

Got my hand dirty on GPS trajectory dataset. This data set consists of sequence of the GPS points of trips for users, until the length of trip:

```
SELECT * FROM gps_track;
+---------+------------------+------------------+
| user_id |       lat        |       lon        |
+---------+------------------+------------------+
| 1       | 39.984702        | 116.318417       |
| 1       | 39.984683        | 116.31845        |
| 1       | 39.984611        | 116.318026       |
| .       | .                | .                |
| 2       | 26.162202        | 119.943787       |
| 2       | 26.161528        | 119.943234       |
| 2       | 26.1619          | 119.943228       |
| .       | .                | .                |
| 3       | 22.8143366666667 | 108.332281666667 |
| 3       | 22.81429         | 108.332256666667 |
| 3       | 22.81432         | 108.332258333333 |
| .       | .                | .                |
| 4       | 32.9239666666667 | 117.386683333333 |
| 4       | 32.9235166666667 | 117.386616666667 |
| 4       | 32.9232833333333 | 117.386683333333 |
| .       | .                | .                |
+---------+------------------+------------------+
```

I can get the `COUNT` of GPS points for each `user_id 1, 2,3,..` etc.

```
SELECT distinct user_id
    , COUNT(lat) AS lat_count
FROM gps_track
GROUP BY user_id
```

How do I then get the median of the number of GPS points in all the trips? Not the median point for each user. Here's the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=18f2d30135029ee78418928135266fba) for sample points from my dataset.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342898/function-to-calculate-median-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

```
SELECT percentile_disc(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY lat_count)
FROM (SELECT user_id
    , COUNT(lat) AS lat_count
FROM gps_track
GROUP BY user_id) du;
```