# Unable to calculate median - SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, median

I am trying to computer the median number of transactions in each category.
A few notes (as the dataset below is a small snippet of a much larger dataset):

- An employee can belong to multiple categories
- Each transaction's median should be > 0
- Not every person appears in every category

The data is set up like this:

```
|  Person | Category | Transaction |
|:-------:|:--------:|:-----------:|
| PersonA |   Sales  |      27     |
| PersonB |   Sales  |      75     |
| PersonC |   Sales  |      87     |
| PersonD |   Sales  |      36     |
| PersonE |   Sales  |      70     |
| PersonB |   Buys   |      60     |
| PersonC |   Buys   |      92     |
| PersonD |   Buys   |      39     |
| PersonA |    HR    |      59     |
| PersonB |    HR    |      53     |
| PersonC |    HR    |      98     |
| PersonD |    HR    |      54     |
| PersonE |    HR    |      70     |
| PersonA |   Other  |      46     |
| PersonC |   Other  |      66     |
| PersonD |   Other  |      76     |
| PersonB |   Other  |      2      |
```

An ideal output would look like:

```
| Category | Median | Average |
|:--------:|:------:|:-------:|
|   Sales  |   70   |    59   |
|   Buys   |   60   |    64   |
|    HR    |   59   |    67   |
|   Other  |   56   |    48   |
```

I can get the average by:

```
SELECT
    Category,
    AVG(Transaction) AS Average_Transactions
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    Category
```

And that works great!

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342898/function-to-calculate-median-in-sql-server) tried to help me find the median. What I wrote was:

```
SELECT
    Category,
    PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Transaction) OVER (PARTITION BY Category) AS Median_Transactions
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    Category
```

But I get an error:

`Msg 8120: Column 'Transactions' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the **GROUP BY** clause`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want using `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Category,
       PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Transaction) OVER (PARTITION BY Category) AS Median_Transactions
FROM table;
```

Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't offer the `PERCENTILE_` functions as window functions and doesn't have a `MEDIAN()` aggregation function.  You can also do this using subqueries and counts.

Answer (score 0):

It's not optimal but this is your solution

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       category,
       PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5)WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY val) OVER (PARTITION BY category) AS Median_Transactions,
       AVG(val) OVER (PARTITION BY d.category)  [AVG]
FROM #data d;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is pretty but it works. I didn't spend time on polishing it

```
with 
avg_t as 
( select category, avg(sales) as avg_sales 
  from sample 
   group by 1), 
mn as 
(  select category, avg(sales) as median_sales 
   from (
     select category, sales , 
            row_number() over  (partition by category order by sales asc) as r , 
            count(person) over (partition by category) as total_count 
     from  sample 
         ) mn_sub 
    where (total_count % 2 = 0 and r in ( (total_count/2), ((total_count/2)+1)) ) or 
           (total_count % 2 <> 0 and r = ((total_count+1)/2))
         
    group by 1 
)
select avg_t.category, avg_t.avg_sales, mn.median_sales  
 from avg_t 
 inner join mn 
 on avg_t.category=mn.category
```