# How to use PERCENTILE_CONT in GROUP BY query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, percentile-cont

I have a table named TabA with the following columns,

```
Id
Currency
Value
Institution
```

Expected Results:

```
Id  Currency  Cnt   Median(Value)   Institution
```

I am getting the values except Median(Value) using the below query,

```
SELECT  Id, Currency,Count(*) AS Cnt,
-- PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) within GROUP (PARTITION BY Value) AS Median(Value) ,
MAX(Institution) AS Institution 
FROM  TabA
WHERE Institution like  '%Fed%' 
GROUP BY Id,Currency
ORDER BY Institution
```

when Include PERCENTILE_CONT, I am getting the following error.

```
The function PERCENTILE_CONT must have a WITHIN GROUP clause
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: You need a subquery [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uWjAW-uZ). It's not clear why you are grouping by Id and ordering by max(institution) which can be misleading. Isn't Id unique? Sample data and desired output are mandatory here. Similar question: [Unable to calculate median - SQL Server 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61412397/unable-to-calculate-median-sql-server-2017), but distinct won't work in this case. Subquery works.

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution. Could you please add it in the answer section!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already metioned in comments you need subquery for percentile_cont, then you can aggregate data:

```
with tmp as (
  select id, currency, institution,
         percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by value) 
           over (partition by id, currency) AS mv
  from tabA WHERE Institution like  '%Fed%' )
SELECT Id, Currency, Count(*) AS Cnt, max(mv) as MedianValue,
       max(Institution) AS Institution 
FROM  tmp
GROUP BY Id, Currency
ORDER BY Institution
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/uWjAW-uZ)