# Calculate median date difference for ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have table with transactions data. I have to calculate median difference between transactions in days for every client. In table are 3 important columns:

```
**Transaction_id | client_id| transaction_date**
```

Transaction_id is primary. Have u any idea how i can handle it?

EDIT: One important info: I don't know how many transactions customers have.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function to Calculate Median in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1342898/2029983)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I think you want `percentile_cont()`.  That would be:

```
select distinct client_id,
       percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by day_diff) over (partition by client_id) as median_day_diff
from (select t.*,
             datediff(day,
                      lag(transaction_date) over (partition by client_id order by transaction_id,
                      transaction_date
                     ) as day_diff
      from t
     ) t
```