# Query to calculate median passing values in many columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, median

I'm translating a SAS project to T-SQL and there's a need to calculate the median.

There is ready to use median function in SAS (e.g.: `SELECT MEDIAN(col1, col2, col3, col4) FROM myTable`), but in SQL Server that doesn't exist.

I've researched and found some good examples to calculate median in T-SQL, but I don't know how to use it in my query as follows:

```
SELECT 
    'test' AS colTest,
    CASE 
        WHEN c1 < 0 
           THEN (10) 
           ELSE 0 
    END AS myMedian --this 10 value is just for example, it should be get from a median function
FROM 
    #tb_test
```

I've been trying with the example below, and got this:

```
CREATE TABLE #tb_test 
(
     id INT, 
     c1 INT, 
     c2 INT, 
     c3 INT, 
     c4 INT
)

INSERT INTO #tb_test VALUES(1, 2, 4, 6, 8)
INSERT INTO #tb_test VALUES(2, -1, 3, 5, 7)

SELECT * FROM #tb_test;
```

The table is:

```
|id| c1| c2| c3| c4|
+--+---+---+---+---+
|1 | 2 | 4 | 6 | 8 |
|2 |-1 | 3 | 5 | 7 |
```

As far as I got to calculate the median for those columns is:

```
--my getMedian query:
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        id, Names, Results
    FROM
        (SELECT id, c1, c2, c3, c4
         FROM #tb_test) p
    UNPIVOT
        (Results FOR Names IN (c1, c2, c3, c4)
        ) AS UNPIVOT_tb_test
)
SELECT DISTINCT PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) 
       WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Results) 
       OVER (partition BY id) AS Median
FROM cte
```

Which results in:

```
|Median|
+------+
|4     |
|5     |
```

I've tried to include this **getMedian** in the final query, but no success.
This desired final query would be:

```
SELECT 
    'test' AS colTest,
    CASE 
        WHEN c1 < 0 
           THEN ([is it possible to use the getMedian query here?]) 
        ELSE 0 
    END AS myMedian
FROM 
    #tb_test
```

And its respectively desired result:

```
|colTest | myMedian |
+--------+----------+
|test    | 4        |
|test    | 5        |
```

Does anyone knows how can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function to Calculate Median in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342898/function-to-calculate-median-in-sql-server) See also this excellent article https://sqlperformance.com/2014/02/t-sql-queries/grouped-median

Comment: I've read it when I was researching, but I think that in those answers there is not a specification about how to calculate median for a set of columns, only for the values in one column.

Comment: Just unpivot the columns then calculate median on that. Unclear if you want the median for every row (in which case unpivot and calculate in a subquery or `apply`) or if you want a single median from all columns, all rows, in which case unpivot then calculate over the whole set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[According to @AaronBertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/median), the fastest way to calculate a median is to use `OFFSET/FETCH`.** What this does is selects the one or two middle vaues by doing calculations on the total number of values, and averages them.

You can either do this in subquery in the `SELECT`:

```sql
SELECT
    t.*,
    Median = CASE WHEN c1 < 0 THEN (
      SELECT AVG(m.n * 1.0) FROM (
        SELECT n
        FROM (VALUES (t.c1),(t.c2),(t.c3),(t.c4)) v(n)
        ORDER BY v.n
        OFFSET (4 - 1) / 2 ROWS    -- 4 is the number of values
        FETCH NEXT 1 + (1 - 4 % 2) ROWS ONLY  -- again 4
      ) m
    )
    ELSE 0 END
FROM #tb_test t
```

Or you can put it in an `APPLY` and select it afterwards

```sql
SELECT
    t.*,
    Median = CASE WHEN c1 < 0 THEN m.Median ELSE 0 END
FROM #tb_test t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT AVG(m.n * 1.0) FROM (
        SELECT Median = n
        FROM (VALUES (t.c1),(t.c2),(t.c3),(t.c4)) v(n)
        ORDER BY v.n
        OFFSET (4 - 1) / 2 ROWS    -- 4 is the number of values
        FETCH NEXT 1 + (1 - 4 % 2) ROWS ONLY  -- again 4
    ) m
) m
```

Comment: Even Better than what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are quite close, I simply added a join to get the following, is this what you want?

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        id, Names, Results
    FROM
        (SELECT id, c1, c2, c3, c4
         FROM tb_test) p
    UNPIVOT
        (Results FOR Names IN (c1, c2, c3, c4)
        ) AS UNPIVOT_tb_test
), medians as (
  SELECT distinct id, PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) 
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Results) 
         OVER (partition BY id) AS Median
  FROM cte
)
select t1.*
  , t2.Median -- add here whatever condition you wish, e.g. case c1<0, etc.
from tb_test as t1 inner join medians as t2 on (t1.id=t2.id)
```

Comment: In fact, I had already done it that way too, but since there is 48 distinct sets of columns I must use to get the median, I was looking for a more simpler-elegant solution. But thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

The function does exist.  It just requires `apply`:

```
select t.*, m.median
from #test t cross apply
     (select top (1) percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by c) over () as median
      from (values (t.c1), (t.c2), (t.c3), (t.c4)) v(c)
     ) m;
```

This sort of cheats a little.  The function is really a window function, not an aggregation function.  The `select top (1)` just returns one row.

Comment: I think you want `percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by c) over ()`

Comment: @Gordon,I've tested and worked as @Charlieface mentioned.But how can I put it inside the query as I asked?I've tried this: `SELECT CASE WHEN (c1<0) THEN (select m.median from #tb_test t cross apply (select top(1) percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by c) over () as median from (values (t.c1), (t.c2), (t.c3), (t.c4)) v(c)) m) ELSE 0 
END AS myMedian, 'other columns' AS OtherColumns FROM #tb_test` .  But returned **Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.**.

Comment: @jMarcel If you use `CROSS APPLY` you don't need a subquery, just `SELECT CASE WHEN (c1<0) THEN m.median ELSE 0 END, OtherCols ... FROM #t CROSS APPLY (select top (1)...` Or you can remove the apply and run it like this `SELECT CASE WHEN (c1<0) THEN (select top(1) percentile_cont....`

Comment: Thanks @Gordon! And thank you too @Charlieface, I've adjusted as you explained above and it worked as expected.