# Include Medians for grouped query .

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this query that I need to graph.
The graph will show Total patients, patient Longest wait (minutes) and patient Median wait for each location.  I need to include Medians in my query, and that is where I am stuck.

Example Raw Data:

[image]

Query I have so far w/o Medians:

```
    SELECT 
[Location],
      count([Patient_Number]) Total,
      MAX([WaitTime_Min]) LongWait
     
  FROM MyTable
  where
  [Location] in ('AMB', 'PEDS', 'WALK')
  and [EDNurse] is NULL
  group by [Location]
```

Output:

[image]

I need help getting a last column of Medians for WaitTime (from the raw data) for each location.  Any help would be appreciated;  Thanks!!

Desired Output:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function to Calculate Median in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342898/function-to-calculate-median-in-sql-server)

Comment: can you group by location and use last?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are `PERCENTILE_CONT(for continues values), PERCENTILE_DISC(for discrete value)` methods in Sqlserver 2012 for doing that. you can read more about it [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2645/sql-server-2012-analytical-functions-percentilecont-and-percentiledisc/).

```
SELECT 
[Location],
      count([Patient_Number]) Total,
      MAX([WaitTime_Min]) LongWait,
     max(MedianDisc) MedianDisc, -- Discrete median
     max(MedianCont) MedianCont -- continues median
  FROM (
          select  m.*, PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY WaitTime_Min)   
                            OVER (PARTITION BY [Location]) AS MedianCont  
      ,PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY WaitTime_Min)   
                            OVER (PARTITION BY [Location]) AS MedianDisc
            from myTable m
             where
  [Location] in ('AMB', 'PEDS', 'WALK')
  and [EDNurse] is NULL
   
  )tt
 
  group by [Location]
```

**Update**:
based on performance issues in this method that Aaron commented, I add a pure SQL calculation for Median:

```
select  [Location], 
        count([Patient_Number]) Total,
        MAX([WaitTime_Min]) LongWait,
        AVG(1.0 * LongWait) As Median
FROM
(
    SELECT [Location],
       [Patient_Number]  Total,
       [WaitTime_Min]  LongWait
        , ra=row_number() over (partition by [Location] order by [WaitTime_Min])
        , rd=row_number() over (partition by [Location] order by [WaitTime_Min] desc)
    from myTable m
    where [Location] in ('AMB', 'PEDS', 'WALK')
      and [EDNurse] is NULL
) as x
where ra between rd-1 and rd + 1
group by [Location]
```

Comment: Just keep in mind these functions are not fantastic. See [this article](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/02/t-sql-queries/grouped-median), for example, and some other ideas in the [Grouped Median section here](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/08/sql-plan/improving-the-top-top-descending-median-solution).

Comment: Just curious Farshid, why are you uinsg MAX for medianDisc and MedianCOnt?

Comment: @MonksDen You got the below error if don't want to use the aggregate function for it: Column 'tt.medianDisc' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Ok, I just want to make sure that I am getting the actual Median value.  Thanks!

Comment: It's not working.  It is pulling the MAX wait time number from the waittime column.  For example, if you have: 1,2,5,10,18  it's pulling 18 as the median.  I need the median not the max?  Any ideas?

Comment: @MonksDen I don't think so, I just add the median calculation section and didn't any change your init code. BTW I updated my code.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I added another solution based on your blog. if you have any idea about it, I am eager to hear from you.

Comment: The updated query works much better.    The only change is that partition by should be "Patient_Number" instead.  it was giving me wrong patient totals with "location".  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @MonksDen I thought your grouping was based on Location as you said in your question cause of that I assumed that way, any time.

Comment: When I use Location, the totals are all wrong.  When I replace the partition by with Patient_Number, the totals are correct but the Medians are slightly off.  When I keep what you have in your updated query and only remove "where ra between rd-1 and rd + 1 ", then totals are correct now but medians are off.  Any ideas?  I think some tweaking is needed?

Comment: @MonksDen your desired output is grouped by Location field, isn't it?

Comment: @MonksDen which field do you want to use in your median calculation? and which field do you want to use in a grouping?

Comment: Median should be WaitTime_Min and grouping is Location.  I only changed it before because I was seeing the totals off.  That fixed the totals but then as the data was coming in, I saw the medians were not correct.  For example, if I use your query w/o any changes, I get total of only ONE WALK location patient, where in reality there are 13 according to the raw data.  But when I replace that with the Patient_Number, the totals reflect the correct number but then Medians are off.

Comment: @MonksDen Maybe your WaitTime_Min field maybe have null values.