# Use row_number() to take middle row in a set of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, median, row-number

previously I opened an issue asking how to take the first row in a set of records which were resolved brilliantly. Pitifully my customer changed his request a little after so this time I'm asking your help to find the middle row in a set of records i.e. having this:

| TemperatureID | CastingID | TemperatureDateTime | TemperatureValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1421294 | 1073513 | 2021-01-07 11:53:00.000 | 1648 |
| 1421295 | 1073513 | 2021-01-07 11:54:00.000 | 1698 |
| 1421296 | 1073513 | 2021-01-07 11:57:00.000 | 1699 |

I have to take the 1421295 record, whereas having an even number either the middle + 1 or middle - 1

So starting from this query, which return the **1421294** record to be clear

```
SELECT * 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            CastingID, TemperatureValue, TemperatureDateTime
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CastingID ORDER BY CastingID) RN
        FROM Production.Temperatures
        where YEAR(TemperatureDateTime) = 2021 and PhaseID = 250
    ) A
    WHERE RN = 1 and year(A.TemperatureDateTime) = 2021
```

can I obtain the result I want or I have to change my approach?

Comment: So you want the "median row"? Will there always be 3 rows, or could there be more/less? Does this answer your question? [Function to Calculate Median in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342898/function-to-calculate-median-in-sql-server)

Comment: Side note: Don't use syntax like `WHERE YEAR(TemperatureDateTime) = 2021`, it's not SARGable; use proper date boundaries (`WHERE [Date] >= {Start Date} AND [Date] < {End Date}`). Also, there is no point (in the above) rechecking that the date is in the correct range in the outer query if you're already doing so in the `WHERE` of the inner query.

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for the tip. To answer your question there could be even 30 rows with same CastingID but I awlays need the median i.e. the 15th or the 16th

Comment: I tried the solutions proposed in the link you posted @Larnu, but unfortuntely they didn't solve my problem since the guy who opened the issue wanted to calculate the median value between a set and not just retrieve the entire row

Comment: `PARTITION BY x ORDER BY x` doesn't make sense. *By definition* all rows within each partition share the same value of `x`. Therefore, trying to order them within their partition by that same `x` value defines no sort value.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that's true but the OVER function actually requires an ORDER BY, so I chose CastingID even though the TemperatureDateTime column would made more sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Updated to use a cte.
Edit2: Updated to use a join rather than a sub-select to handle multiple castingIds

Since `ROW_NUMBER()` is going to give us a continuous set of values, why not find `MAX(RN)`, divide by 2 and then round? If the `MAX(RN)` is odd, you'll get the true median, if it's even you'll get rounded down. There's likely a cleaner way to do this but something like this:

```
  WITH cte AS (
        SELECT 
            temperatureID 
            ,castingID
            ,temperatureValue
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY castingID ORDER BY TemperatureDateTime) AS RN
        FROM Temperatures
)
SELECT
    * 
FROM cte AS c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        castingID
        ,CEILING(CONVERT(DECIMAL(7,2),MAX(RN)) / 2) AS med
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY castingID
) AS m ON c.rn = m.med AND c.castingID = m.castingID
```

Here is a SQL Fiddle with the result of the query:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5b3aebf3ab4ced946c90a435d9edce3c

There's three use cases (all with different `castingID`).

1.) Odd number of rows

2.) Even number of rows

3.) A single row

Comment: I do think you cannot use alias `A` in the where clause, see: [DBFIDDLE: Invalid object name 'A'](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=91f7c68eb4709f4fe82ae50ec6099d11)

Comment: True. We can use a CTE though.

Comment: Hi @EdwardRadcliffe, thanks for your answer, I tried using your query but SQL Server gives me this error: `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Comment: I thinks it's because when I have an even number of records it returns me 2 rows, is it correct?

Comment: Stefano - that was an oversight on my part. I've updated the query in the comments to use a join which should handle multiple castingIds

Comment: Ush thank you very much, it actually works very well. I'll mark that as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query without WHERE work

```html
SELECT *
FROM Customers
ORDER BY customer_id 
LIMIT 1 OFFSET (SELECT COUNT(*) / 2 FROM Customers) - 1;
```