# How to find median value for a given colum in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to find the median value for 'score' colum of the table mentioned below

**score_table(userid,score)**

Please help me to find the median score using mysql :) thank you

Comment: its hard to believe that if you google `mysql` and `median` nothing is returned.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating the Median with Mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401158/calculating-the-median-with-mysql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291152/simple-way-to-calculate-median-with-mysql