# Explaining Solution to Previously Answered Post: Finding Median in MySQL

Tags: mysql, median

I need to calculate the median value in MySQL. I saw the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291152/simple-way-to-calculate-median-with-mysql).

But, I didn't understand part of it. The solution provided enter code here is as follows:

```
SELECT x.val from data x, data y
GROUP BY x.val
HAVING SUM(SIGN(1-SIGN(y.val-x.val))) = (COUNT(*)+1)/2
```

What is `data x` and `data y` in the context of the original question? Usually FROM is followed by the table name. But, then why are 2 tables listed when the question refers to only one? Can someone explain how this solution works? Also, I didn't understand this part: `HAVING SUM(SIGN(1-SIGN(y.val-x.val)))` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is data x and data y in the context of the original question?
>   Usually FROM is followed by the table name. But, then why are 2 tables
>   listed when the question refers to only one?

In the original question, `data x, data y` joins the table to itself, creating a cartesian product.  The original table had 7 rows, and by joining every row against every other row, the resulting product is 49 rows.

> Also, I didn't understand this part: `HAVING
>   SUM(SIGN(1-SIGN(y.val-x.val)))`.

Essentially, this function determines for every value how many values are less than the one being examined.  It then compares this total to half the count + 1... and then selects that value as the median.

It does this by subtracting the value (`x.val`) from the value it is comparing (`y.val`).  It then uses the `SIGN` function to convert the result to `-1`, `0`, or `1`.  It then subtracts this value, and then takes the `SIGN` again.  So if the `y.val` value is less than the `x.val` value it that is being compared to, the end result would be a `1`.  For example, let's say `y` is `3`, and `x` is `5`.

```
3 - 5 = -2
SIGN(-2) = -1
1 - (-1) = 2
SIGN(2) = 1
```

If `y` were `5`, and `x` was `3`... the end result would be `0`:

```
5 - 3 = 2
SIGN(2) = 1
1 - 1 = 0
SIGN(0) = 0
```

Summing the results of these comparisons gives us a number that indicates how many values come before the value that we're examining.  It then compares this `SUM` against `COUNT(*) + 1 / 2` to find the middle range...

Comment: Hi @Michael Fredrickson, Thank you for the excellent explanation! I learned something new.