# I need to find median in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, statistics, median

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simple way to calculate median with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291152/simple-way-to-calculate-median-with-mysql)

I need find the median  of each corresponding id value in mysql. Means i need to get like median of 1=3 and median of 2=5 and median of 3=7.Can any one help me..? Thanks in advance.

```
id | val
--------
 1    4
 3    7
 1    2
 2    2
 3    9
 2    8
 3    3
```

Comment: @Scorpi0: In the example he is calculating the median per group. His calculations are correct.

Comment: You can find many [answers][1] here.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291152/simple-way-to-calculate-median-with-mysql

Comment: See this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342898/function-to-calculate-median-in-sql-server

Comment: There is no aggregate method in MYSQL for finding  median value.You have to calculate manually. This question is already solved .see this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342898/function-to-calculate-median-in-sql-server