# How is this advanced SQL syntax constructed?

Tags: mysql, statistics

I have done the SQL beginners and advanced courses at W3Schools successfully, and cannot find any other free advanced onine SQL course. I am having a problem with the SQL syntax in the accepted answer in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291152/simple-way-to-calculate-median-with-mysql), covering the calculation of the median value of a column. My questions are:

1. After 'from' come two variables. Does that mean that data are selected from two tables, and if so, how would the formula be if I just require the median value of one column of one table?
2. The OP/TS named this columns 'id' and 'val'. Why then is 'x.val' selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SELECT x.val from data x, data y` means to cross-join table `data` with itself. I'm pretty sure it eventually just finds the median for one column, and this is a trick to help calculate that median.

To understand this better (and note that I don't totally understand it), try this:

1. Set up a table with some sample data - say 5-8 rows to begin with
2. Promote the `HAVING` values to the `SELECT` list
3. Get rid of the `HAVING` clause

So your query will look something like this:

```
SELECT x.val, SUM(SIGN(1-SIGN(y.val-x.val))), (COUNT(*)+1)/2
FROM data x, data y
GROUP BY x.val
```

Then take a look at the results and you'll be able to get more insight into the logic. Also see if you can follow the calculation when you track it row by row.

Finally, note that the query isn't so much advanced as it is specialized. I mean, it is advanced and all, but it's the math gymnastics rather than the query semantics that are probably giving you trouble. Don't sweat it if you don't understand this right off the bat :)

As for why `val` is selected - that's the column the OP is trying to calculate the median for. The `id` is probably there because it's generally a good idea to have a PK on every row. It's not needed for the calculation so it's not included in the query.

Comment: Although I still don't quite understand how this x.value and y.value thing works, I now can calculate the median, and that is what matters most. Nonetheless, would you happen to know a tutorial that explains that x. and y.value matter?

Comment: I don't know of one offhand. The best I can recommend is to Google "sql cross join tutorial". I saw a couple promising looking articles. The sample query cross joins a table *to itself*, but when I Googled "cross join table to itself" the hits were more about specific questions rather than general articles. Just make sure you don't get too hung up on this. In 15+ years of doing database work for a living I can't recall having cross-joined a table to itself. Nowadays many of the math-jockey queries are done via analytic functions - Google "sql analytic functions tutorial" for more info.