# Populate second table with averages from first

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, average

I've got two tables, *transactions* and *listings*.

*transactions* list all of my transactions that occur each day. I have a column in transactions that lists the price of each transacted item. Several transactions occur each day. I would like to take the median or mean of all transactions in each day, and populate a new column in *listings* with this information.

So my end result would have a column in *listings* called daily_price_average, that takes the average price of individual transaction information from *transactions*.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Or how could I do this using a view?

Comment: Step 1 - decide whether you want the mean or median.  If you want the median, decide which type you want.

Comment: I will go for the mean.

Comment: Don't do this in a table, use a `VIEW`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a view as:

```
create v_listings as
    select l.*,
           (select avg(price) 
            from transactions t
            where date(t.transactiondate) = l.date
           ) as daily_price_average
    from listings l;
```

To do the update, you would first be sure `daily_price_average` is a column in listings:

```
update listings join
       (select date(t.transactiondate) as tdate, avg(price) as avgprice
        from transactions
        group by date(t.transactiondate)
       ) td
       on listings.date = td.tdate
    set daily_price_average = td.avgprice;
```

Both of these assume that `listings` has a column called `date` for the average.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`INSERT... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html)

For average

```
INSERT INTO averages (day, average)
  SELECT date, AVG(price)
  GROUP BY date
```

Getting the median is... [complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7263925/1064767).