# MongoDB find median

Tags: mongodb

I would like to upon user request graph median values of many documents.  I'd prefer not to transfer entire documents from the database to my application solely for purposes of determining median values.

I understand that development is still planned for a [median aggregator](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4929) in MongoDB, however I see that currently the following operations are supported:

- [sort](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)
- [count](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/count/#dbcmd.count)
- [limit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/#pipe._S_limit)

Short of [editing mongo source code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/pull/523), Is there any reasonable way I can combine these operations to obtain median values; for example, to sort values, count them, and limit to return median values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate the median in MongoDB aggregation framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456095/calculate-the-median-in-mongodb-aggregation-framework)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that [editing Mongo source code](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4929) is the only solution.