# JPA method to implement median

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, median

I use JPA data Mongo DB and crudrepository, Now I need a method to calculate median. This is the main method which I need to get a median price.

```
findByDateBetweenAndInstrumentIdOrderByPriceDesc
```

Is it possible throw defined words in JPA?

Answer (score 0):

No that's not possible.

You have to use Mongo aggregation framework:

[Calculate the median in MongoDB aggregation framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456095/calculate-the-median-in-mongodb-aggregation-framework/22329287)