# How to calculate the average number of documents in each group in MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDb collection called UserRecords. It stores all records for our users, where each user can have many records.

I am trying to calculate some basic statistics related to the number of records per user.

Specifically I would like the mean, median and mode of the number of records per user.

So far I have a query that groups all UserRecords by User_Id (uid) and counts the number of UserRecords for each user.

```
db.UserRecords.aggregate([
{$group: 
    {_id:{"uid":"$uid"},
    count:{$sum:1}}}
])
```

My query produces results that look like the following:

```
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "uid" : UUID("f22880a8-94d2-4524-a974-a2e500e2c2a2")
    }, 
    "count" : 100
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "uid" : UUID("1b3a3b81-d107-4345-8df5-a5ef00e23598")
    }, 
    "count" : 200
}
```

I would need my query to calculate the average of all the "count" values.  For example, suppose the above results were the only 2 groups produced.  I would need my query to do (100 + 200) / 2 = 150 and print that value of 150 to the console.

Does anyone know what I can add to my query to accomplish this?

*Edit, I would ideally like my result structure to be:

```
{
    "mean": 1000,
    "median": 850
    "mode": 900
}
```

Comment: You should be able to chain another aggregation pipeline stage doing a group + $avg.

Comment: please provide the expected result structure.

Comment: And where would that average go? below `mode`?

Comment: @codemonkey yes

Comment: @codemonkey `avg` is nothing but `mean`

Comment: look at the similar [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456095/calculate-the-median-in-mongodb-aggregation-framework), [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56747771/how-to-calculate-avg-median-min-max-in-mongodb-query) for median calculation, i think this kind of calculations should be in client side language not in mongodb query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments it might not be good practice to calculate `median` and `mode` in db level but just for enthusiasm try this.

Btw its calculating median and mode on the accumulated `count` of `uid`s.

```js
db.UserRecords.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { "uid": "$uid" },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            mean: { $avg: "$count" },
            numbers: { $push: "$count" }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            median: {
                $function: {
                    body: function(numbers) {
                        if (numbers.length === 0) return 0;
                        numbers.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; });
                        var half = Math.floor(numbers.length / 2);
                        if (numbers.length % 2) return numbers[half];
                        return (numbers[half - 1] + numbers[half]) / 2.0;
                    },
                    args: ["$numbers"],
                    lang: "js"
                }
            },
            mode: {
                $function: {
                    body: function(numbers) {
                        return Object.values(
                            numbers.reduce((count, e) => {
                                if (!(e in count)) {
                                    count[e] = [0, e];
                                }

                                count[e][0]++;
                                return count;
                            }, {})
                        ).reduce((numbers, v) => v[0] < numbers[0] ? numbers : v, [0, null])[1];
                    },
                    args: ["$numbers"],
                    lang: "js"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            numbers: 0
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: very impressive, nice answer!

Comment: Thanks for asking this questions. I also learnt something new!

Comment: I think another (maybe simpler) way of calculating mode is to just do 2 group stages.  The first stage groups users by User_Id, then the second stage would group by the "count" field of the first stage.  You could then sort the results in the descending order, and the first document would contain the mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can `group` with `null` as `_id`, in this case, the result is a single
document with your accumulator expression applied to every document in the pipeline

According to [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-by-null)

> If you specify an _id value of null, or any other constant value, the $group stage calculates accumulated values for all the input documents as a whole

```
db.UserRecords.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {"uid": "$uid"},
            count: {$sum: 1}
        },
    },
    {
        // will result in a single document which contains sumaries of
        // the previous groups data
        $group: {
            _id: null,

            recordsCount: {$sum: '$count'}, // the number of records in the collection
            usersCount: {$sum: 1}, // i.e "groups count"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            mean: {$divide: ['$recordsCount', '$usersCount']}
            // ... you can add other measures here
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: `median` and `mode` will require a complex query, as sorting is required. In the second `$group` stage a field that holds sorted "count" is needed for those measures

Answer (score 0):

For most of the common stats, like count, min, max, mean, they can be achieved by using `$sum`, `$min`, `$max`, `$avg` in a `$group`

For mode, it can be calculated by `$group` with `$count`, then `$sort` + `$limit: 1` to get max count.

For median, it can be achieved by latest MongoDB v7.0 `$median` operator.

Sample in `$facet`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "stat": [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            count: {
              $sum: 1
            },
            min: {
              $min: "$key"
            },
            max: {
              $max: "$key"
            },
            mean: {
              $avg: "$key"
            },
            median: {
              $median: {
                input: "$key",
                method: "approximate"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "mode": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$key",
            "count": {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            count: -1
          }
        },
        {
          "$limit": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YIp3wf-JHvd) (Mongo Playground not yet support v7.0 at the time of writing. You may be able to view the effect in later releases of playground)