# Calculating Median for columns mysql

Tags: php, mysql, median

I have the following columns in mysql,

Area, Price, Type, Quarter, Year etc.

What I am trying to do, is calculate the median for every area (Juffair, Adliya, Mahooz) over these conditions.

A typical row would look something like this

```
Burhama, 500, Apartment, 3, 2014..
Burhama, 600, Apartment, 3, 2014
Juffair, 800, Apartment, 3, 2014 etc.
```

What I want it to do is display a table with (Area - Median). So it should take all of Juffair and calculate the median. etc.

What it is doing is: Displaying every single area(duplicate times) with it's price next to it.

Moving around the loops, I get it to display, only the area's, but calculates the medians, across all the area's, instead of just the one that it is suppose to.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
function calculate_median($arr) {
sort($arr);
$count = count($arr); //total numbers in array
$middleval = floor(($count-1)/2); // find the middle value, or the lowest middle value
if($count % 2) { // odd number, middle is the median
    $median = $arr[$middleval];
} else { // even number, calculate avg of 2 medians
    $low = $arr[$middleval];
    $high = $arr[$middleval+1];
    $median = (($low+$high)/2);
}
return $median;
}
?>


<?php

$array = array('Juffair', 'Adliya', 'Mahooz', 'Burhama' , 'Manama');
$price = array();
//connect
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stats 
WHERE `rentsale` = 'Rent'
and `type` = 'Apartment' 
and `area` IN('".implode("', '", $array)."') 
and `beds` = '2' 
and `quarter` = '3' 
and `year` = '2014'") 
//die
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) {

$area = $info['area'];
$array = array('Juffair', 'Adliya', 'Mahooz', 'Burhama' , 'Manama');
foreach( $array as $area ) {
$price[] = $info['price']; 
$home_values_array = $price;
$median_home_value = calculate_median($home_values_array);
}
?>
<table>
<tr>
<TD><?php echo $area; ?></TD>
<TD><?php echo $median_home_value; ?></TD>
</tr>
</table>
<?php

}


 ?>
```

Comment: Maybe you should do this in SQL, here's an example on how to compute medians in any SQL RDBMS: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7263925/3227403

Comment: You can have SQL do these calculations for you, rather than looping through result sets. 
Have a look at these answers.  
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1291296/32763

Comment: Hi, That would be great if I am only going to run a few queries, the result set is in the hundreds of thousands and I would like to be able to modify it in the script.

Comment: How would MYSQL calculate the median for every Area that is Unique and do that in an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to calculate the median in MySQL, I would suggest using variables (which neither of the referenced answers suggests):

```
select area, avg(price) as median
from (select s.*,
             (@rn := if(@a = area, @rn + 1,
                        if(@a := area, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) seqnum
      from stats s cross join
           (select @a := '', @rn := 0) vars
      order by area, price
     ) s join
     (select area, count(*) as cnt
      from stats
      group by area
     ) a
     on s.area = a.area
where 2*seqnum in (cnt - 1, cnt, cnt + 1)
group by area;
```

The above query calculates the median for all the data.  The first subquery enumerates the values, and the second gets the total count.

If you want a filter, such as as by year, then you need to add it to both subqueries.

Comment: Thanks, got it figured out.

Comment: I am a little bit lost here , not having done it this way before. Can you tell me where I need to input the WHERE clause?

Comment: @JohanFourie . . . You would need to add the `where` clause to both subqueries.