# World database exercise

Tags: mysql

European city which population is closest for defect to the median of European population?

I try with this code, but  I always have an error with the where condition in the subquery

```
Select city.name,city.population from city
join country
on city.countrycode=country.code and country.continent='europe'
where city.population<(
avg(country.population)
where country.continent='europe')
order by city.population desc;
```

Comment: Put SELECT before `avg(country.population)`. That is a subquery and need to be started with SELECT.

Comment: @leonardo_palma MEDIAN <> MEAN

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple way to calculate median with MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291152/simple-way-to-calculate-median-with-mysql)

Comment: It doesn't work even with the select

Comment: Ok, i find out the solution, my mistake was repeating the where clause meanwhile i already declared it in the join!

Answer (score 1):

```
Select city.name,city.population from city
join country
on city.countrycode=country.code and country.continent='europe'
where city.population < (select avg(country.population)
where country.continent='europe')
order by city.population desc;
```

Comment: I cannot see that this answer addresses the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i find out the solution, my mistake was repeating the where clause meanwhile i already declared it in the join:

```
Select city.name,city.population from city
Join country
On city.countrycode=country.code and country.continent=’europe’
Where (select avg(country.population))>city.population
Order by city.population desc
Limit 1;
```