# Calculation of median value for every day

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, select

Can anybody help me to calculate median value for each date?

```
activity
user_id login_time  bet
105 2018-04-01  20966119
102 2018-04-01  2027700
105 2018-04-01  5478000
104 2018-04-01  78448383
104 2018-04-06  49730093
101 2018-04-06  2750000
103 2018-04-15  16625000
105 2018-04-16  
106 2018-04-19  3095584
```

Output

```
login_time   median
2018-04-01   13222060
2018-04-06    26240047
```

My query

```
SELECT login_time, IF(SUM((IFNULL(bet, 0)) / 2) % 2 = 0, SUM(IFNULL(bet, 0)) 
    / 2 + 1, SUM(IFNULL(bet, 0)) / 2) 
 AS median
FROM activity
WHERE login_time BETWEEN '2018-04-01' AND '2018-04-06'
GROUP BY login_time;
```

Whay is wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: @fa06 , I updated

Comment: Are you sure you want the median?  Can you explain your current attempted logic?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, yes, I need median value. May be my query is wrong. But need for help

Comment: @Raymond Nijland, this result I've got in Excel. What should I change to get rigtht result?

Comment: Did you mean the average? because 26240047 ==> (49730093 + 2750000) / 2

Comment: "What should I change to get rigtht result? " Start by updating the question.. That the output is a result of the query that's below and not a expected result set.. Makes your question beter to read and understand for other further readers.

Comment: @Vanojx1  No. Excel shoes shuch result with function =МЕДИАНА(J9:J10) (russian edition)

Comment: Ok i going to ask now are you using MySQL or Excel?

Comment: If you use MySQL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291152/simple-way-to-calculate-median-with-mysql

Comment: @Raymond Nijland  
I use sql of cource, but check result in Excel sometimes

Comment: "Did you mean the average? because 26240047 ==> (49730093 + 2750000) / 2" topicstarter and @Vanojx1.. Vanojx1 is more or less right Median wil use the AVG of two orderd middle rows when the items count is even..Median wil pick the middle item from a order list when the item count is odd.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `group_concat()` trick for this, if your data is not too large.  This works pretty well:

```
select a.login_time,
       substring_index(substring_index(group_concat(bet order by bet), ',', ceil(count(*) / 2), ',', -1)
from activity a
where a.login_time between '2018-04-05' and '2018-04-18'
group by a.login_time;
```

If there are an even number of examples, then this chooses the value on the lower side.  Medians are not well defined for sets with an even cardinality.

Comment: thanks, but: ERROR 1582 (42000): Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'su
bstring_index'

Comment: this does not handle median complety..Correct median calculation wil use the AVG of two orderd middle rows when the items count is even..median wil pick the middle item from a order list when the item count is odd. This query does only handle the even count