# How do I join an ascending ordered field with the same field ordered descending?

Tags: mysql

I need **a query that adjoins a list of data (simply one field of float data from a table) ordered ascending with the same field ordered descending**.

*For context's sake, I'm practicing my (very) rudimentary and (very) rusty SQL (MySQL, specifically). The larger problem I'm working to solve is [this HackerRank question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-20/problem), which is to compute the median of the `LAT_N` field from the `STATION` table.*

My strategy is to return from a table with the data ordered ascending in the first column (`up_LAT_N`) and the data ordered descending in the second column (`down_LAT_N`) the *average of the first row that satisfies the condition (`cond`) that the datum in the ascending ordered field is greater than or equal to the datum in the descending ordered field*. This average would be the median.

I've tried the following:

```
SELECT  up.LAT_N AS up_LAT_N, 
        down.LAT_N AS down_LAT_N,
        CASE 
            WHEN up.LAT_N >= down.LAT_N THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END AS cond
FROM
    (SELECT LAT_N FROM STATION ORDER BY LAT_N) up,
    (SELECT LAT_N FROM STATION ORDER BY LAT_N DESC) down
```

...but I the ordering doesn't seem to be preserved. I'm thinking I could basically do a 'join' of these two columns, but I'm not sure how to introduce an index to each of these on which to join.

Thanks, in advance!

**EDIT: Sorry for the confusion: I wasn't looking for the solution to broader question of calculating the median -- just a little nudge to help me implement my own attempt at solving this problem!**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple way to calculate median with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291152/simple-way-to-calculate-median-with-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no meaning to order subquery. If you need visual ordering you need to do it on the outer query.

```
SELECT  up.LAT_N AS up_LAT_N 
        down.LAT_N AS down_LAT_N
        CASE 
            WHEN up.LAT_N >= down.LAT_N THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END AS cond
FROM STATION up, STATION down
ORDER BY up.LAT_N, down.LATN DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

> The larger problem I'm working to solve is this HackerRank question, which is to compute the median of the LAT_N field from the STATION table.

You can compute the median directly with the following query :

```
SELECT AVG(dd.lat_n) as median_val
FROM (
SELECT d.lat_n, @rownum:=@rownum+1 as `row_number`, @total_rows:=@rownum
  FROM station d, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
  WHERE d.lat_n is NOT NULL
  -- put some where clause here
  ORDER BY d.lat_n
) as dd
WHERE dd.row_number IN ( FLOOR((@total_rows+1)/2), FLOOR((@total_rows+2)/2) )
```

Tested in [this db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b9xp5oyyBuM2HE2jE3ja4E/0) (with an even number of rows, which is the most complex case to handle when it comes to medians).

See [this excellent SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291152/simple-way-to-calculate-median-with-mysql) for an explanation of the technique.

Comment: Rather than copy/paste (with minor edits) an answer from another question, you should simply flag this question as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @Nick : ok, done. The question was not originaly targeted on solving the median computation, but rather on what I imagine was an intermediate step towards that. My answer was meaning to point the SO to a direct solution for his global use case (and I quoted the original link, and tested the solution !).

Comment: Agreed that the question wasn't specifically targeted at the median, but your answer was, so it's more appropriate to call it a duplicate. But definitely brownie points for testing the solution. :-)

Comment: Yep, y'all are both correct: I'm wasn't asking for an answer to the median computation...just some direction for the intermediate step. Was hoping to [struggle some more/hopefully learn something along the way and] take it to the finish line from there. :) Appreciate the help nonetheless!