# How to calculate the median value of an associative array from a MySQL query?

Tags: php

I get an associative array of values using `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`
and I get the following array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => 12.00000 ) [1] => Array ( [value] => 12.00000 ) [2] => Array ( [value] => 1001.00000 ) [3] => Array ( [value] => 1001.00000 ) [4] => Array ( [value] => 1.00000 ) [5] => Array ( [value] => 101.00000 ) [6] => Array ( [value] => 155.00000 ) [7] => Array ( [value] => 100.00000 ) [8] => Array ( [value] => 100.14300 ) [9] => Array ( [value] => 10123.12000 ) )
```

How to get the median value? I can't just use `arsort` and get the middle value because it's an array within array and I get stuck

How to do it?

Edit: I tried using `array_column($array, 'value')`, and now it extracted the value, then I used `asort` and got the following output:

```
Array ( [4] => 1.00000 [0] => 12.00000 [1] => 12.00000 [7] => 100.00000 [8] => 100.14300 [5] => 101.00000 [6] => 155.00000 [2] => 1001.00000 [3] => 1001.00000 [9] => 10123.12000 )
```

So the problem is that `asort` does sort the array, but only for the output, but it's not actually sorting it, so for example `$array[0]` is not the minimum value (`1.0000`) in my case, but it's actually the original value `12.00000`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291152/simple-way-to-calculate-median-with-mysql ... assuming you don't need the other values later

Comment: How are you using the array? The keys are still maintained so `0` always has the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract `value` fields from your array with:

```
$values = array_column($array, 'value');
// now `sort` and do what you need
arsort($values);
```

`arsort` **sorts array**. If you open a manual you will see that `arsort`

> sorts an array such that array **indices maintain their correlation** with the array elements they are associated with.

So, obviously you need another function, I suppose just `rsort`.

Comment: I just tried it, but it doesn't really sort the array, I added the example in the original post

Comment: `arsort` __sorts array__. Obviously, you do something wrong.

Comment: Look at the original associative array, it was an array containing arrays, and you can see it looked like `( [0] => Array ( [value] => 12.00000 )` so maybe `array_column` did filter out the `value` but left the original `[0]`? You can see that in the output `arsort` did sort the array but left the original numbers, I need to filter them out as well?