# how to count timediff for each users mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

let's say i have the data table like this

```
ID  users_Id   createdAt
1   12         '2020-01-01'
2   12         '2020-01-03'
3   12         '2020-01-06'
4   13         '2020-01-02'
5   13         '2020-01-03'
```

how do i get the timediff for every transaction and every users so the results are just like this

```
MAX   MIN   AVERAGE    MEDIAN
3     1     3          3
```

explanation:

- the maximum of timediff happen in users_id 12 when '2020-01-03' until '2020-01-06' (3 days)
- the mininum of timediff happen in users_id 13 when transaction between '2020-01-02' and '2020-01-03'
- the average are 3 (2 days in users_Id 12 + 3 days in users_Id 12 + 1 days in users_Id 13)/count of the users_id (12 and 13)

Comment: Add your code which you try for expected result and what's you got.

Comment: MySQL version??

Comment: 5.7 sir @SalmanA

Comment: this timediff are difficult for me sir, i always had a example of timediff for every row, not for every id's so im lil bit confused in here @Tushar

Comment: Do you really need the median? It is much more complicated to compute than the other columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this (*without computing the median*):

```
SELECT MIN(diff) AS `MIN`, MAX(diff) AS `MAX`, SUM(diff) / COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS `AVG`
FROM (
  SELECT ID, user_id, DATEDIFF((SELECT t2.createdAt FROM test t2 WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id AND t1.createdAt <= t2.createdAt AND t2.id <> t1.id LIMIT 1), t1.createdAt) AS diff
  FROM test t1
  WHERE order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8)
) DiffTable
WHERE diff IS NOT NULL
```

---

The median is much more complicated to compute on MySQL. But you can use something like this based [on this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1291296/3840840). As you can see the query get very messy. There is no function like `SUM` or `AVG` on MySQL to get the median.

```
SELECT MIN(DiffTable.diff) AS `MIN`, MAX(DiffTable.diff) AS `MAX`, SUM(DiffTable.diff) / COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS `AVG`, MIN(median.diff) AS `MEDIAN`
FROM (
  SELECT ID, user_id, DATEDIFF((SELECT t2.createdAt FROM test t2 WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id AND t1.createdAt <= t2.createdAt AND t2.id <> t1.id LIMIT 1), t1.createdAt) AS diff
  FROM test t1
  WHERE order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8)
) DiffTable, (
  SELECT m1.diff FROM (
    SELECT ID, user_id, DATEDIFF((SELECT t2.createdAt FROM test t2 WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id AND t1.createdAt <= t2.createdAt AND t2.id <> t1.id LIMIT 1), t1.createdAt) AS diff
    FROM test t1
    WHERE order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8)
  ) m1, (
    SELECT ID, user_id, DATEDIFF((SELECT t2.createdAt FROM test t2 WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id AND t1.createdAt <= t2.createdAt AND t2.id <> t1.id LIMIT 1), t1.createdAt) AS diff
    FROM test t1
    WHERE order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8)
  ) m2
  WHERE m1.diff IS NOT NULL AND m2.diff IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY m1.diff
  HAVING SUM(SIGN(1-SIGN(m1.diff-m2.diff))) = (COUNT(*)+1)/2
) median
WHERE DiffTable.diff IS NOT NULL
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=150a0c85422ade2410d9a186a8aa4329)

Comment: thankyou very much sir, i almost forgot sir, i forgot to add coloumn order_status_id, so it will counted if order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8). where do i can add order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8), is it after "from test t1" or after "where diff is not null?"

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL < 5.7, I would use a correlated subquery to recover the last `created_at` of the same user. This gives you all columns that you expect excepted the median:

```
select
    max(diff) max_diff,
    min(diff) min_diff,
    avg(diff) avg_diff
from (
    select
        t.*,
        datediff(
            created_at, 
            (select max(t1.created_at) from mytable t1 where t1.user_id = t.user_id and t1.created_at < t.created_at) 
        ) diff
    from mytable t
) t
```

Comment: thankyou sir, but i think this query lil bit wrong because you dont define that t1 table, and mysql cant read that

Comment: thankyou very much sir, i almost forgot sir, i forgot to add coloumn order_status_id, so it will counted if order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8). where do i can add order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8)? is it after "t1.createdAt < t.createdAt" or after "from mytable t"?