# Calculating a simple median on a column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, common-table-expression, median

I'm struggling to find the solution for a simple median problem. Given a table `my_table` with just one column:

```
my_column | 
----------|
10        |
20        |
30        |
40        |
50        |
60        |
```

How can I call a function to return the median of 35?

I can't figure out how to make this syntax work when all I want is to return the median value:

```
SELECT
  PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY my_column) OVER ( PARTITION BY my_column)
FROM
  my_table
```

Comment: 35 is the mean, not the median.

Comment: @BillKarwin Not true at all.  The above data set does not have a single median value, as it has an _even_ number of values.  As a result, typically statisticians will report the _mean_ of 30 and 40 as the median.  In this case, it is 35, which coincidentally also happens to be the mean.

Comment: Point taken, I retract my comment. :)

Comment: Sorry, I should have used better sample data to keep it more clear!

Comment: One way of retracting a comment is to delete it.

Comment: Since you tagged it with mariadb:  MariaDB 10.2 has "windowing functions" similar to MySQL 8.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would just use `distinct`, with an empty `OVER()` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY my_column) OVER () median
FROM my_table
```

Comment: Note: this answer does not apply to MySQL, only MariaDB (`PERCENTILE_CONT` doesn't exist in MySQL).

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution that I tested in MySQL 8.0:

```
with ranked as (
  select my_column, 
    row_number() over (order by my_column) as r,
    count(my_column) over () as c 
  from my_table
),
median as (
  select my_column 
  from ranked 
  where r in (floor((c+1)/2), ceil((c+1)/2))
)
select avg(my_column) from median
```

Output:

```
+----------------+
| avg(my_column) |
+----------------+
|        35.0000 |
+----------------+
```

I borrowed the method from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7263925/20860 but adapted it to MySQL 8.0 CTE and window functions.

Answer (score -1):

You may try:

```sql
SELECT col_median
FROM
(
    SELECT PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY my_column) OVER () AS col_median
    FROM my_table
) t
LIMIT 1;
```

### Demo

Notes: The `PERCENTILE_CONT` function is a *window* function, whose output, in this case, can only be determined after the entire column has been scanned.  As a result, the output from the subquery above is actually your column, along with a new column, having the same median value in all rows.  But, since you just want to report the median as a single number, I use a `LIMIT 1` outer query to obtain that single median value.

Comment: Perfect! If I wanted to get the 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 0.90 percentiles as well would I just follow that same pattern?

Comment: For the entire table, yes, that should work (play around with my demo link to try it out).

Comment: As per that Demo link, this works in MariaDB, but not MySQL8.0 or earlier.