# Subquery in LIMIT function

Tags: sql-limit

A median is defined as a number separating the higher half of a data set from the lower half. Query the median of the Northern Latitudes (LAT_N) from STATION and round your answer to  decimal places.

Hi, Can anyone please tell me why this query won't work?

```
select round(lat_n, 4) from station 
order by 1 asc 
limit select floor(count(lat_n)/2) from station, 1;
```

I'm using a subquery under limit function to return the number (249).

Comment: What is your _version_ of SQL?  E.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.

Comment: Sorry, it's MySQL.

Comment: Google for "MySQL median"

Comment: Can you please let me know why my query after limit won't work? Also, MySQL doesn't have MEDIAN().

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple way to calculate median with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291152/simple-way-to-calculate-median-with-mysql)