# How to calculate the median category wise in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to find median of total scores region wise. I have got the solution after trial and error on data but the query is not in a optimized way. i need a efficient mysql query for this problem.

#Thanks for the solutions#

Edit: first `exam` has to be filter from `assessment` table and second `total_score needs` to be summed for all subject of each student using `studentassessment` table. Then finally region wise median needs to be calculated.

[image: database schema]

````
SELECT region,
      Avg(total_score) AS median
FROM   (SELECT row_num,
              region,
              total_score,
              region_cnt
       FROM   (SELECT Row_number()
                        OVER (
                          partition BY region
                          ORDER BY total_score) AS row_num,
                      region,
                      total_score,
                      Count(region)
                        OVER (
                          partition BY region)  AS region_cnt
               FROM   (SELECT i.region     AS region,
                              Sum(S.score) AS total_score
                       FROM   tredence.assesment A
                              INNER JOIN tredence.studentassessment S
                                      ON A.id_assessment = S.id_assessment
                              INNER JOIN tredence.studentinfo i
                                      ON i.id_student = S.id_student
                       WHERE  A.assessment = 'Exam'
                       GROUP  BY S.id_student,
                                 i.region
                       ORDER  BY region,
                                 total_score) t) r
       GROUP  BY 1,
                 2,
                 3,
                 4
       HAVING row_num IN ( Floor(region_cnt / 2), Ceil(region_cnt / 2) )) z
GROUP  BY region
ORDER  BY median DESC ```

tables and columns:
|Assessments    |student_info|student_assessment|
|---------------|------------|------------------|
|course_code    |course_code |id_assessment     |
|batch_code     |batch_code  |id_student        |
|id_assessments |id_student  |date_submitted    |
|assessment_type|gender      |is_banked         |
|date           |region      |score             |

Output:
|Region       |Median|
|-------------|------|
|North Region | 82   |
|London Region| 80   |
|Scotland     | 80   |
|Ireland      | 76   |
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple way to calculate median with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291152/simple-way-to-calculate-median-with-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you reduce the set to the following.  Note: id_student isn't required at this point in the calculation.

```
CREATE TABLE tscores (
    id          int primary key auto_increment
  , region      int
  , id_student  int
  , total_score int
  , index (region, total_score)
);

INSERT INTO tscores (region, id_student, total_score) VALUES
    (1, 1000, 40)
  , (1, 1001, 50)
  , (1, 1002, 30)
  , (1, 1003, 90)
  , (2, 1101, 50)
  , (2, 1102, 51)
  , (2, 1103, 55)
;
```

SQL and Result:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
        SELECT region, total_score
             , ((COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY region) + 1) / 2) AS n
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY region ORDER BY total_score) AS rn
          FROM tscores AS t
     )
SELECT region
     , truncate(AVG(total_score), 2) AS med_score
  FROM cte1 AS t
 WHERE rn IN (ceil(n), floor(n))
 GROUP BY region
;

+--------+-----------+
| region | med_score |
+--------+-----------+
|      1 |     45.00 |
|      2 |     51.00 |
+--------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.004 sec)
```

Still not quite enough detail.  But here's SQL that runs against your schema, minus the typos I think you had in your SQL:

```
WITH tscores AS (
                     SELECT i.region     AS region
                          , Sum(S.score) AS total_score
                       FROM tredence.assessments A
                       JOIN tredence.studentassessment S
                         ON A.id_assessment = S.id_assessment
                       JOIN tredence.studentinfo i
                         ON i.id_student = S.id_student
                      WHERE A.assessment = 'Exam'
                      GROUP BY S.id_student
                             , i.region
     )
   , cte1 AS (
        SELECT region, total_score
             , ((COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY region) + 1) / 2) AS n
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY region ORDER BY total_score) AS rn
          FROM tscores AS t
     )
SELECT region
     , truncate(AVG(total_score), 2) AS med_score
  FROM cte1 AS t
 WHERE rn IN (ceil(n), floor(n))
 GROUP BY region
;
```

Comment: When asking a performance related question, it's usually a good idea to provide the exact schema (create table statements), along with all existing indexes, plus the explain plan result for the SQL in question.  Some test data (in the form of insert statements) would be helpful as well.  I don't have enough points to comment directly to the poster.  :)

Comment: i have added the database schema. i think now it will be easier to get to solution. please check.