# median in django annotation

Tags: mysql, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-orm

Im using MySQL server v5.8 as database, how to find median price in query like this:

```
 price_query = Product.objects \
                        .filter(price_query) \
                        .annotate(dt=Trunc('StartDate', frequency)) \
                        .values('dt') \
                        .annotate(avg_price=Avg('Price'), std_price=StdDev('Price'),
                         count=Count('Price'), max_price=Max('Price'),
                         min_price=Min('Price'), median='???') \
                         .order_by('dt')
```

response is look like this

```
{"date":"2021-05-01T00:00:00Z","avg_price":4326.666666666667,"std_price":20.548046676563168,"min_price":4300.0, "max_price":4350.0,"count":3}, {...}, {...}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of MySQL is this? Depending on the version, calculating the median might be... involved. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291152/simple-way-to-calculate-median-with-mysql

Comment: yap i saw it. but how i implement this in django, not as rawsql. If it possible

Comment: @party911 did you figure this out?